# Building a supervised multi label predictor with sparse training data

Tags: machine-learning, document-classification, liblinear

I am trying to build a supervised multi label predictor.

I have tried using a liblinear binary classifier with a model per label but I am not getting good results probably because the training data is very sparse (many of the input documents do not have any labels).

Does someone know if there is a better algorithm I can use for sparsely labelled data?

Comment: did you find any method to handle sparse training data?